# Getting URI for playlist based on specific search query in Spotify Android SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, spotify

I am building an Android app that utilizes the Spotify Android SDK and I would like to dynamically fetch a list of playlists that match a certain name or description.

I have not been able to find a better way to do this than to make a GET request to the Web API, specifically, the search endpoint, in which case I would need a simple String as a search query and would get a list of playlists with matching metadata.

I assume this would work but I was hoping I would be able to do this using the Android-specific SDK.